# How to tell the difference between an Angel and Jinn?

Tags: jinn, malaikah, animals

It is said that angels and jinns can shapeshift into any animal. That being said ; how can I identify whether an animal is an Angel, JINN or actual Animal  ?

Comment: purpose of this question

Comment: Is there any evidence angels turn into animals?

Answer (score -2):

Hadith

حَدَّثَنَا قُتَيْبَةُ بْنُ سَعِيدٍ، حَدَّثَنَا اللَّيْثُ، عَنْ جَعْفَرِ بْنِ رَبِيعَةَ، عَنِ الأَعْرَجِ، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ، رضى الله عَنْهُ أَنَّ النَّبِيَّ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏

‏ إِذَا سَمِعْتُمْ صِيَاحَ الدِّيَكَةِ فَاسْأَلُوا اللَّهَ مِنْ فَضْلِهِ فَإِنَّهَا رَأَتْ مَلَكًا وَإِذَا سَمِعْتُمْ نَهِيقَ الْحِمَارِ فَتَعَوَّذُوا بِاللَّهِ مِنَ الشَّيْطَانِ الرَّجِيمِ فَإِنَّهُ رَأَى شَيْطَانًا ‏"

‏ ‏‏ قَالَ هَذَا حَدِيثٌ حَسَنٌ صَحِيحٌ ‏‏

Abu Hurairah [may Allah be pleased with him] narrated that:

The Prophet said: “when you hear the crowing of the roosters, then ask Allah of His bounty, for verily they have seen an angel. When you hear the braying of a donkey, then seek refuge in Allah from Shaitan, [the rejected] for, verily, it has seen a Shaitan.”

Sahih (Darussalam)

Jami` at-Tirmidhi 3459
In-book : Book 48, Hadith 90

No animal is an angel or jinn.they only see them and by this hadith quoted above we get to know about the presence of Angels and jiins.
I hope this clear your query

Comment: http://sunnah.com/muslim/39/192 and http://sunnah.com/muslim/39/190